# R lavaan: quadratic regression of latent variables

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, quadratic

Is there a way of specifying a quadratic regression between latent variables in lavaan? (Or in another R package for structural equation modeling?) That is, latent variable y, `yLatent`, is a quadratic function of latent variable x, `xLatent`, such that `yLatent ~ 1 + xLatent + xLatent^2`.

Apparently there is no direct way to express this in a lavaan model. I have a kludgy way of approximating it by creating an additional latent variable from the squared values of observed (aka manifest) x data, and this additional latent variable stands in as a sort of approximation to `xLatent^2`. I show a minimal example of this below. But is there a better way to do this?

First, I create some simulated data: three observed `x` variables and three observed `y` variables. Notice in the pairs plot that the `y`'s are a quadratic function of the `x`'s. Notice also that I append columns with the `x` variables squared (not plotted).

```
library("psych")
library("lavaan")
library("lavaanPlot")

# Create simulated data:
set.seed(47)
N = 100
noise = 1.5
x1 = runif(N,-3,3)
x2 = x1+runif(N,-noise,noise)
x3 = x1+runif(N,-noise,noise)
xM = rowMeans( cbind(x1,x2,x3) )
yM = 3 + 0*xM - 0.5*xM^2
y1 = yM+runif(N,-noise,noise)
y2 = yM+runif(N,-noise,noise)
y3 = yM+runif(N,-noise,noise)
theData = cbind( x1 , x2 , x3 , y1 , y2 , y3 ,
                 # N.B.: append columns with squared x values:
                 x1sq=x1^2 , x2sq=x2^2 , x3sq=x3^2 )
psych::pairs.panels( theData[,1:6] )
```

[image]

Next, I use lavaan to create a latent `x` variable based on the observed `x`'s, and a latent `y` variable based on the observed `y`'s. I'd like to estimate a quadratic regression, something like `yLatent ~ xLatent + xLatent^2`, but the kludgy approach here is to estimate another latent factor `xSqLatent` from the squared `x` values.

```
# Structural equation model:
QuadModel = '
  xLatent =~ x1 + x2 + x3
  # Next line: kludgy way of approximating xLatent^2 
  # instead of desired xSqLatent = xLatent^2
  xSqLatent =~ x1sq + x2sq + x3sq 
  yLatent =~ y1 + y2 + y3
  yLatent ~ xLatent + xSqLatent
'
semQuad = sem( QuadModel , data=theData ) 
summary( semQuad ) 
lavaanPlot( model=semQuad , graph_options=list(rankdir="TB") ,
            coefs=TRUE , stand=FALSE , stars=c("regress") )
```

[image]

The result, above, does pick up the quadratic trend, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach looks similar to what is called the "product indicator" approach in SEM. Some related code (with references) is [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/semTools/man/indProd.html) and [here](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/16521_c51516aca5a1430cabf9f6dec4b7ddb5.html).

There is another popular approach, called "[Latent Moderated Structural Equations](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02296338)", that does not require you to estimate/compute latent variables. It deals with the fact that latent quadratic effects/interactions involve products of normal distributions, and those products lead to a difficult likelihood (where the likelihood has integrated out latent variables). So they approximate that likelihood with a mixture of normal distributions. This is not available in lavaan, but I believe it is available in the nlsem package and perhaps others.

The Bayesian way is conceptually simpler because you sample the individual latent variables, then take products, then condition on the products. I believe that Sik-Yum Lee has some papers on this from about 20 years ago (sometimes under the topic of "nonlinear SEM"). More recently, there is some work from Brandt and colleagues (for example, [here](https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2021.1957663)). In my experience, it is challenging to get the MCMC algorithm to work efficiently and reliably there.

Comment: Ed, *thank you* for the pointers to the "product indicator" approach to interactions. It's reassuring to see that my home-grown method for latent quadratic trend has been previously used. Because of your use of the term, "product indicator", my literature searches have been more productive. for multiplicative interactions (e.g., here: https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2014-14617-001) and suggested for quadratic trend too (e.g., here: https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2014-01991-007). I agree MCMC Bayesian with explicit latent values could work - but scary duration for comparing many big models.